# Navigation Drawer Activity Null NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer, buttonclick

Navigation Drawer Activity

I'm having trouble defining a button onclick function within OnCreate, NullPointerException and close app

fragment_main.xml

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="206dp" />
```

Oncreate function (MainActivity.java)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));


    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            button.setText("Button Text Change");
        }
    });

}
```

but if I define onclick in xml button works well

```
public void changeText(View v)
{
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText("Button Text Change");
}
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="changeText"
    android:layout_marginTop="206dp" />
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat error ?

Comment: where you are calling `changeText` ?

Comment: android:onClick="changeText" calling changeText function

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get a ***reference*** to the button you need to use `findViewById` from the `fragment`, like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));


    final Button button = (Button) mNavigationDrawerFragment.getView () .findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            button.setText("Button Text Change");
        }
    });

}
```

Again you are doing it wrong here:

```
public void changeText(View v)
{
    final Button button = (Button) mNavigationDrawerFragment .findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText("Button Text Change");
}
```

A more effective way will be to have a *member* variable at `class` level just like `mNavigationDrawerFragment`, for example:

```
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            //Al setup stuff you have....


    button = (Button) mNavigationDrawerFragment.getView () .findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            button.setText("Button Text Change");
        }
    });

}
public void changeText(String s)
{
    button.setText(s);
}
```

As always there is a lot of useful information on the [Button Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: button = (Button) mNavigationDrawerFragment .findViewById(R.id.button);

not have findViewById, but I test 

button = (Button) mNavigationDrawerFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.button);

but error still

Comment: Sorry I forgot about getView ()